# Is the Weierstrass function strictly non-monotonic across every interval?

Tags: derivatives, intuition, fractals

I have a strong suspicion that the Weierstrass function is non-monotonic across every interval, though this suspicion is rooted in the visualization of its generation. I don't know how to prove it, nor am I certain about whether the non-monotonicity is strict or not, though I suspect it is strict.

One way to prove strict non-monotonicity across every interval would be to prove the following, which seems to me to be a simple target:

$$\forall x,y \in \Bbb R\biggr( W(x) \ne W(y) \iff \exists z \in [x,y] \biggr [W(z) < \min(W(x), W(y)) \lor W(z) > \max(W(x),W(y)) \biggr] \biggr)$$

Perhaps another way to prove it would be via the proof for the nowhere-differentiability of the Weierstrass function, because maybe nowhere-differentiability implies strict non-monotonicity across every interval?

[image]

[The Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Weierstrass's function is famously nowhere differentiable. A monotonic function is differentiable almost everywhere, as mentioned in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function#Some_basic_applications_and_results). Thus, Weierstrass's function cannot be monotonic on any interval.

In fact, a much stronger condition is true: Any function of [bounded variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_variation) must be differentiable almost everywhere. This is known as [Lebesgue's differentiation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem) and is proved as theorem 4.52 in Karl Stromberg's *Introduction to classical real analysis*, as well as in the above wiki link to the theorem.

Comment: Where may I find the proof for why a monotonic function is differentiable almost everywhere? Can't there be a monotonic function composed of an uncountably infinite number of break-points, for example?

Comment: @user110391 I'm sure I learned this theorem Karl Stromberg's book, as I mention in my edit.